# Problems With Locking Threads Until a Function Returns?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety

This is a very basic example of what is going on in a project I am working on. The scenario is basically one function that calls other functions that all lock resources of the current thread until they finish. Here is a small example.

```
void functionA()
{
    lockUntilDone();
    //do some magic
    functionB();
    //do some more magic
}

void functionB()
{
    lockUntilDone();
    //make some more magic
    functionC();
}

void functionC()
{
   lockUntilDone();
   //make a little bit more magic
}
```

lockUntilDone() - locks the resources in the current thread until the function finishes it's execution and is out of scope.

I am just starting out learning about using threads and processes. **What problems can occur during running functionA?** What if this scenario gets expanded, so instead of three levels of locking it goes 4,5,6 and so on? Or is this a typical way of locking a thread and handling resources in a function?

Answer (score 1):

There are no additional problems with 3, 4 and more nesting levels. General problem is when you scale from 1 level to several. std::mutex is not recursive, that means you can't lock it twice, even if you try to do that from the thread that already has locked it. So `lockUntilDone` has to use recursive_mutex's. They are provided by STL too and you can use them, but they are less efficient as non recursive ones.

But there is another consideration: situation when you have to lock the same objects from multiple nested functions is not typical. That may be OK, but that's a symptom that code must be refactored. For example lock can be too coarse and can be split to several locks. Or some of the methods are actually private methods which are always called from locked context and do not require additional locking.

Personally, I would make locking only in functionA. If functionB is not private and can be called outside of functionA, then I'll make private functionB without locking which does all work and use it from functionA and from public functionB which does the locking and calls the internal one.